# ReactJS: How to refresh component without 1 click delay

Tags: reactjs

I'm learning React and I have problem with refreshing a child component when parent's state is changed by another child. I found that I should use `componentWillReceiveProps()` and it works but with one click delay. What should I change to get immediate update?

I've posted my code on CodePen to make it easier to explain. If it's better to post it here directly please let me know, and I will update.

[FCC: PomodoroClock - CodePen](https://codepen.io/Radioaktywnyja/pen/PLwaQg)

Problems:

- When I increase or decrease length in ClockSetter (+ and - buttons) then parent's state changes immediately but session length in Timer shows previous value.
- When I click reset button parent's state changes immediately, but nothing happens with ClockSetter's length and Timer's lenght changes to ClockSetter's. After another click on reset both children lenght's changes to parent's state.
- If I try to increase or decrease after reset (instead of second reset click) it goes crazy (i can't find the rule how it changes)

Is it possible to make it only with React or should I start learning Redux?

Edit: My code

```
import React from 'react';
import './PomodoroClock.scss';

class PomodoroClock extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      sessionLength: 25,
      breakLength: 5,
    };
    this.handleTime = this.handleTime.bind(this);
    this.handleReset = this.handleReset.bind(this);
  }

  handleTime(type, time) {
    this.setState({
      [type]: time
    });
  }

  handleReset() {
    this.setState({
      sessionLength: 25,
      breakLength: 5,
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <ClockSetter clockType="break" initialLength={this.state.breakLength} handleTime={this.handleTime} />
        <ClockSetter clockType="session" initialLength={this.state.sessionLength} handleTime={this.handleTime} />
        <Timer sessionLength={this.state.sessionLength} reset={this.handleReset}/>
        <span>TEST: State session - {this.state.sessionLength} State break - {this.state.breakLength}</span>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class ClockSetter extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      length: this.props.initialLength
    }
    this.handleDecrease = this.handleDecrease.bind(this);
    this.handleIncrease = this.handleIncrease.bind(this);
    this.refresh = this.refresh.bind(this);
  }

  handleDecrease() {
    if(this.state.length > 1) {
      this.setState ({
        length: this.state.length - 1
      });
    }
    this.props.handleTime(this.props.clockType+'Length', this.state.length - 1);
  }

  handleIncrease() {
    if(this.state.length < 60) {
      this.setState ({
        length: this.state.length + 1
      });
    }
    this.props.handleTime(this.props.clockType+'Length', this.state.length + 1);
  }

  refresh() {
    this.setState({
      length: this.props.initialLength
    });
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(props) {
    if(this.state.length !== this.props.initialLength) {
      this.refresh();
    }
  }

  render() {
    let type = this.props.clockType;
    return(
      <div className="clock-setter">
        <div id={type + '-label'} className="first-letter-capitalize">{type + ' Length'}</div>
        <span id={type + '-decrement'} className="button" onClick={this.handleDecrease}>-</span>
        <span id={type + '-length'}>{this.state.length}</span>
        <span id={type + '-increment'} className="button" onClick={this.handleIncrease}>+</span>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Timer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      activeCountdown: 'Session',
      length: this.props.sessionLength
    }
    this.refresh = this.refresh.bind(this);
  }

  refresh() {
    this.setState({
      length: this.props.sessionLength
    });
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(props) {
    if(this.state.length !== this.props.sessionLength) {
      this.refresh();
    }
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div className="timer">
        <span id="timer-label">{this.state.activeCountdown}</span>
        <div id="time-left">{this.state.length}</div>
        <span id="start_stop" className="button">Start/Stop</span>
        <span id="reset" className="button" onClick={this.props.reset}>Reset</span>
      </div>
    );
  }
}


export default PomodoroClock;
```

Comment: Regarding `is it better to post it here directly`: yeah, it would be. If you [edit] your question, there's this file icon with a `</>` that you can use to embed a snippet in your question.

Comment: Did you follow a tutorial to get the code you have now? There are many issues in your code.. it's hard to address just your one issue without explaining why the overall architecture is bad. For instance.. `componentWillReceiveProps` is actually deprecated now because it led to exactly the type of problems you are dealing with now

Comment: Also, there's an ancient proverb: "you'll know when you need Flux/Redux". :)

Comment: @grooveplex that proverb is dumb. Many people do not know this, and nowadays there are many competing solutions to redux depending on the needs of the application.

Comment: Yes it is entirely possible to do this with just React. You can build everything and anything with just React. Redux and other state management helpers do just that.. help. but you don't *need* them. That doesn't mean you shouldn't use them, but it's important to know how to do everything with React so you can make a more informed decision about when you need the extra help from more libraries / patterns

Comment: Answer finished! hope that helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's refactor your code in such a way that fixes the immediate issue while at the same time addresses some bad practices and antipatterns that will cause you headaches moving forward.

And because you're just starting, this is the perfect time to learn about [hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) because they will make your code much more simple and easier to follow.

The main pitfall in your code is **duplication of state**. Let's start with the Timer component.

You are setting its initial state `length` to be the value of its parents state `sessionLength`. Even though you can perceive this to be some type of "initial" state and then afterwards the Timer's `length` will be independent of `sessionLength` once the countdown starts, this is not necessary. In fact.. duplication of state is not necessary in 99% of situations.

So what state *should* the Timer have? I would reckon that the timer might have its own internal counter state such that you display the current time like `this.props.sessionLength - this.state.elapsedTime`, but in your case the Timer isn't actually doing any timing. You're keeping track of the current time at the parent level anyways.

Knowing this.. what should the Timer state be? Nothing! The answer is no state. Timer can be a function, not a class, and receive props and display them.

```
function Timer(props) {
  return (
    <div className="timer">
      <span id="timer-label">Session</span>
      <div id="time-left">{props.sessionLength}</div>
      <span id="start_stop" className="button">
        Start/Stop
      </span>
      <span id="reset" className="button" onClick={props.reset}>
        Reset
      </span>
    </div>
  )
}
```

If that's all you change, this already solves your question.

Next let's look at the ClockSetter component. You are duplicating the state here in the exact same way, and not only that, you have extra handlers which simply call the parents handler `handleTime`, introducing extra steps and complexity which add unnecessary noise to your application. Let's get rid of the state and the extra handlers altogether, and as such we can use a function again, instead of a class:

```
function ClockSetter(props) {
  let type = props.clockType
  return (
    <div className="clock-setter">
      <div id={type + '-label'} className="first-letter-capitalize">
        {type + ' Length'}
      </div>
      <span
        id={type + '-decrement'}
        className="button"
        onClick={() => props.handleTime(type + 'Length', props.length - 1)}
      >
        -
      </span>
      <span id={type + '-length'}>{props.length}</span>
      <span
        id={type + '-increment'}
        className="button"
        onClick={() => props.handleTime(type + 'Length', props.length + 1)}
      >
        +
      </span>
    </div>
  )
}
```

I've inlined the `onClick` handlers for brevity. You could write the named `handleDecrease` and `handleIncrease` functions above the return statement and passed them the `onClick` if you want. That's just a matter of preference though.

***Note: the prop is now `length` not `initialLength`. Make sure to update that when rendering your ClockSetter components**

For this last refactor I have updated your React cdn to point to the latest stable release `16.8.3`, since it includes hooks.

Instead of using a class, let's write a normal function and use the `React.useState` hook. The code looks like this now:

```
function PomodoroClock() {
  let [sessionLength, setSessionLength] = React.useState(25)
  let [breakLength, setBreakLength] = React.useState(5)

  function handleReset() {
    setSessionLength(25)
    setBreakLength(5)
  }

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <ClockSetter
        clockType="break"
        length={breakLength}
        handleTime={setBreakLength}
      />
      <ClockSetter
        clockType="session"
        length={sessionLength}
        handleTime={setSessionLength}
      />
      <Timer
        sessionLength={sessionLength}
        reset={handleReset}
      />
      <span>
        Parent's state TEST: session - {sessionLength} break -
        {breakLength}
      </span>
    </div>
  )
}
```

and instead of having a single state object with keys that reference each timer, since that was the only way with stateful components before, we call `useState` twice each with their respective state and handlers. Now we can remove the `type + Length` argument in our ClockSetter component:

```
onClick={() => props.handleTime(props.length + 1)}
```

This is the entire program now:

```
function PomodoroClock() {
  let [sessionLength, setSessionLength] = React.useState(25)
  let [breakLength, setBreakLength] = React.useState(5)

  function handleReset() {
    setSessionLength(25)
    setBreakLength(5)
  }

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <ClockSetter
        clockType="break"
        length={breakLength}
        handleTime={setBreakLength}
      />
      <ClockSetter
        clockType="session"
        length={sessionLength}
        handleTime={setSessionLength}
      />
      <Timer
        sessionLength={sessionLength}
        reset={handleReset}
      />
      <span>
        Parent's state TEST: session - {sessionLength} break -
        {breakLength}
      </span>
    </div>
  )
}

function ClockSetter(props) {
  let type = props.clockType
  return (
    <div className="clock-setter">
      <div id={type + '-label'} className="first-letter-capitalize">
        {type + ' Length'}
      </div>
      <span
        id={type + '-decrement'}
        className="button"
        onClick={() => props.handleTime(props.length - 1)}
      >
        -
      </span>
      <span id={type + '-length'}>{props.length}</span>
      <span
        id={type + '-increment'}
        className="button"
        onClick={() => props.handleTime(props.length + 1)}
      >
        +
      </span>
    </div>
  )
}

function Timer(props) {
  return (
    <div className="timer">
      <span id="timer-label">Session</span>
      <div id="time-left">{props.sessionLength}</div>
      <span id="start_stop" className="button">
        Start/Stop
      </span>
      <span id="reset" className="button" onClick={props.reset}>
        Reset
      </span>
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <PomodoroClock />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

**[Link to codepen](https://codepen.io/alex-wilmer/pen/vPEzQe?editors=1010)**

We've shaved of over 50 lines of code, it's much easier to read, and there's no potential issue of state being duplicated.

Hope that helps and happy coding! Please ask any questions if you need.

Comment: Wow! You're awesome. Thank you a lot. I didn't even know that there's new react (I used create-react-app when it was 16.7 and still copying and changing old projects instead of using create-react-app again) so I have to update my react, learn about hooks and then I will try to use your tips. Big cold beer for you and I will update when managed with that :)

Comment: @MiloK Have you heard about [`npx`](https://medium.com/@maybekatz/introducing-npx-an-npm-package-runner-55f7d4bd282b)? It's kind of like `npm`, except it'll download the latest version of create-react-app (and other packages) every time. If you have a recent `npm` (6.x or so), you should have it. :)

Comment: you can update an existing create-react-app project by npm installing the latest version of react-scripts. no need to call create-react-app again or migrate anything